# Any user on this computer - no mapped drives work and GPO fails

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

Active Directory and DNS Server is my Win 2008 R2 STD server named "server"

All clients are Win 7 Pro x64 and in the domain

I have one GPO setup for folder redirection of My Documents, Downloads, Favorites, and Pictures.

I have a root folder called "homedir" and each user has their own sub-folder based on their username, which is created for the user when I setup their account on the AD server (\server\HomeDir\%username% and maps to a Z Drive letter)

It's been running fine for the past year.  I setup a new user last November and had no issues with folder redirection working on their new computer when they logged in, the GPO getting pushed to the users account, their own home folder under the Z drive.

One user recently left and a new user was hired.  New user is using old users' computer.  Computer name is Exec-PC.  I setup the new user like any other user.  Just your everyday domain user.

New user logs into Exec-PC:  Folder redirection doesn't work.  GPO fails.  Any user logs into Exec-PC, same thing.
New user logs into any other computer on the domain:  Everything works as it normally should.

Leads me to believe it's a computer issue.  But how?  This computer is no different than 20 other workstations on the network/domain.  Same software, same firewall configuration, some OS, same everything.

When new user (or any user for that matter) logs into Exec-PC - you'll see the Z drive, but if you click it, you'll get an error message saying:  Z:\ refers to a location that is unavailable.  It could be on a hard drive on this computer or on a network.  Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted or that you are connected to the Internet or your network, and try again.

Ok...I'm connected to the network.  I took the computer out of the domain, removed it from DNS, and re-added to the domain.  Didn't help at all.  Ranamed the computer to just "computer01" and that didn't help.

What could cause this crazy computer to behave like this?  I can't figure it out why the computer would be behaving like this (since I've ruled out a user issue).

Any tips/advise?  Anything is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See anything useful in the event viewer (both client and server side) ?

Comment: Also try a manual drive mapping from the command line... you often get more info about why something failed. Try "net use t: \\server\HomeDir". Also, compare a "net use" by itself with same command on other machines.

Comment: Nothing in the event viewer that stands out or points to the issue.  Did a net use t: \\server\HomeDir\%username% and the command completes, but it's the same as the Z drive - same error.  Tried net use on another workstation using t drive.  Works fine.  User can browse their share.

Comment: So it sounds like the drive does actually get mapped so there is some communication but SMB isn't working properly. Take a look at how the network stack is configured. Try enable/disable "Netbios over tcp/ip" to switch from doing SMB over older NetBIOS ports 137/138/139 and newer port 445. Also take a look at what protocols/services are actually bound to the adapter. Are there any firewalls between client and server that could be dropping ports ?

Comment: Disabled/Enabled Netbios over TCP/IP (and chose Default).  Same result on all three settings.  Checked on services and only a few were disabled, but not related to any network operations.  All computers use the windows firewall.  Turned off firewall, same issue.  Turned back on and double checked advanced settings.  Same settings as everyone elses computer in the domain.  Never had to open ports on any computer to get mapped drives working.

Comment: With no event log clues my next steps would be to check whats being sent/received using a sniffer like Wireshark and to start ruling out stuff that might interfere with SMB (such as AntiVirus, 3rd party filesystem extensions, DLP tools etc)

Comment: Without even doing that, I can tell you about the machine.  Uses Microsoft Security Essentials for AV (which I did uninstall, but have since reinstalled).  The only other software installed is Office 2010 Pro, logmein so I get remote access, Google chrome and firefox, usb local printer, Adobe reader, and some software called business in a box.  And software that came w/the computer to operate it.  It's a very basic computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution from this MS KB Article:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942974 (I did the fix it myself section, rebooted, and there you have it...mapped drive works now).